# Custom Labels of Unmanaged Extended Package

Tags: lightning-web-components, package, customlabel

I've been having some issues with packaging and installing my custom labels from my extended package. When I was developing and using the labels (in my extended package)

```
import SUCCESS from '@salesforce/label/BASE.MANUFACTURER';
import ERROR from '@salesforce/label/BASE.MODEL';
```

while the new labels I use are imported using this format

```
import SCAN_DEVICE from '@salesforce/label/c.SCAN_DEVICE';
import REGISTER_DEVICE from '@salesforce/label/c.REGISTER_DEVICE';
```

I was able to upload the package without issue, but when I try to install the (extended ) package alongside my base package, I'm getting this error message

```
Invalid module id "BASE.MANUFACTURER" for type "label". Explicit use of namespace "BASE" in file "customLabels.js" is prohibited. Use default namespace "c" instead.
```

I'm able to deploy to my scratch org, but when I try to deploy the packaged code, I get this error message instead

Invalid reference c.MANUFACTURER of type label in file customLabels.js

I'm not sure if I'm missing a setting, or if there's something I'm missing.